# How to publish mysql data in php by group

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having trouble building a query and displaying the results in PHP, where the results should be grouped.

Given the following sample dataset:

```
+-----------+---------+
| category  | item    |
+-----------+---------+
| fruit     | apple   |
| fruit     | apricot |
| fruit     | banana  |
| fruit     | plum    |
| vegetable | carrot  |
| vegetable | onion   |
| vegetable | potato  |
| vegetable | spinach |
+-----------+---------+
```

And PHP/MySQL code:

```
<?php

    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/SQLTutorial.db.inc.php';

    echo "<p>Here is a test:</p>";

    try {
    $sql = "select category, item from Foods";
      $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . $e->getMessage();
      include 'error.html.php';
      exit();
    }

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
      $ShoppingItems[] = array(
        'category' => $row['category'],
        'item' => $row['item']
      );
    }

    echo "<p>Here are the items by group:</p>";
        
    foreach ($ShoppingItems as $ShoppingItem)
    {
        echo "<p><b>" . $ShoppingItem['category'] . "</b>" 
                . $ShoppingItem['item'] . "</p>";            
    }

?>
```

How would I write the query and php so category is formatted in a single tag, like `<h1>` and the items follow with a different tag, like `<li>` so the result would look like this

## fruit

- apple
- apricot
- banana
- plum

## vegetable

- carrot
- onion
- potato
- spinach

Comment: Show us your code you have written so far.

Comment: Come on. ANY basic tutorial on PHP and MySQL will tell you how to do this. Not good enough.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows negative research effort.

Comment: I have added sample code to better ask for your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response at [Grouping a query with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050220/grouping-a-query-with-php?rq=1%20was%20very%20helpful) was greatly helpful. The following code works pretty well - though I'm sure there is a more elegant solution

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/SQLTutorial.db.inc.php';

echo "<p>Here is a test:</p>";

try {
    $sql = "select * from Foods order by category, item";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

// Loop through results and build the data into a data structure
foreach($result as $row){
    $category = $row['category'];
    $item = $row['item'];
    if (!isset($list[$category])) {// if this is this a category we've never seen before
        $list[$category] = array($item);//then add it to the list with a new array to hold its items.
    } else {
        $list[$category][] = $item;      //otherwise just push the new item onto the category's array of items.
    }    
}

/*        
print "<pre>\n";
print_r($list);  // <-- a very useful debugging tool
print "</pre>\n";
*/            

// And now to print out the formatted results.
foreach ($list as $category => $items) {
    echo "<h1>" . htmlspecialchars($category, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8") . "</h1><ul>\n";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo "<li>" . htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8") . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

?>
```